# How to structure my JAVA classes for multiple clients?

Tags: java, oop

I have an API server with some kind of users let say `A`, `B` and `C`.

I have the same classes for every kinds BUT my problem is that for some kind there are properties who must be hidden or sometime i have to hide the propertie if the API caller isn't the owner of the ressource.

For now I check, for each API function, all the properties i will send back and initialized each to null if isn't in the "authorized" group, but more the number of function is large more the work is heavy...

Any idea if there is a mean to do it more smartly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, what you are looking for basically is to define different attributes for different user types (A, B, C).

You are facing this problem because you are trying to "force" youself to use the same classes for all types. I think simpler and clearer approach is to map each user type with a different set of classes. Here is what I mean:

Current implementation:

PS: And I think this is more like an OOP question, rather than java.

```
         hide properties b,c (just an example)
         +----------- A
         |
         |hide property c (just an example)
K--------+----------- B
         |
         |add property d (just an example)
         +----------- C
```

Proposed approach:

```
K----------------- A
L----------------- B
M----------------- C
```

And organize the KLM classes accordingly to your need. If you can generalize some of their properties in a parent class, let's say P, and move those attributes to that class and move all specific attributes to child classes (K,L,M).

IMHO, this is much cleaner solution.